# How to make attribution with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with session number and id. I need to assign a conversion value based on id in the following way:

1. first session gets 0.4 of conversion value
2. last session gets 0.4 of conversion value
3. All in between should get in total 0.2 of conversion value

If there was just one session then this session gets all (1.0)
If there were two sessions then each get 0.5

```
Ses.Num  id
1        9
1        10
2        10
1        11
2        11
3        11
1        12
2        12
3        12
4        12
```

Expected result

```
Ses.Num id     Conversion_Value
1       9             1
1       10            0,5
2       10            0,5
1       11            0,4
2       11            0,2
3       11            0,4
1       12            0,4
2       12            0,1
3       12            0,1
4       12            0,4
```

Comment: you've tagged `mysql` and `psql` which as far as I can see are not compatible things. One's a database server, and one's a client for a _different_ database server. So which database are you really using?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this conversion value and how it's assigned? The numbers in your expected results don't seem to match up with your description? Why is one row 1 while all the others are decimals?

Comment: @Shawn... I think I'm getting this... Each `ID` should get a total of `1` when summed in this new derived column. If there are 1 session for the id then it gets `1.0`. If there are two then they evenly split each with `.5`. If there are three or more then the first and last get `0.4` and the middle sessions split the remaining `0.2` evenly.

Comment: @JNevill And `id`, not `Ses.Num` determines the session? Yeah, it makes sense that way.

Comment: @shawn `ses.num` determined the session of the `id`. Or maybe that's what you mean. I'm thinking something like `CASE WHEN max(ses.no) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = ses.no CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 1 THEN 1.0 WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 2 THEN .5 ELSE .4 END CASE... ` This is going to get ugly, perhaps it can be tackled with recursion instead. (assuming mysql 8.0 or any other RDBMS)

Comment: @Shawn yes the user Jnevill discribed everything correct. I really struggle to solve this task with SQL. Normal Case statements will not work as i need to assign certain values per ID and i do not know how to do this

Comment: @JNevill with OVER (PARTITION BY id) is really good option!! i will try this. But how to make if i have 5 sessions per one id.
Then i have to make smt like 0,2/MAX(ses.num)-2
meaning there are 3 sessions inbetween 0,2/5-3=0,1 for each session. But what is the code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by id) = 1
             then 1.0
             when count(*) over (partition by id) = 2
             then 0.5
             when row_number() over (partition by id order by ses.num) = 1
             then 0.4
             when row_number() over (partition by id order by ses.num desc) = 1
             then 0.4
             else 0.2 / (count(*) over (partition by id) - 2)
        end) 
 from t;
```

Comment: That's a lot less ugly then I had envisioned it. Bravo.

Comment: That helps I think. Will try it out! Thanks

Comment: @Gordon Linoff

I think in first two raws it should be

when count(session_num) over (partition by id) = 1
             then 1.0
             when count(session_num) over (partition by id) = 2
             then 0.5